# Exact Size of ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: ubuntu

I downloaded ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso but due to limited bandwidth, i don't know if the file is downloaded successfully or did the downloading stop in between and chrome is showing completed download , despite it being not downloaded 100%.
For the current downloaded file,
size:-1.98GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same size as mine. Did you try to open it? You can also check if it complete by running `sha256sum ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso` and comparing it to what is at http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/SHA256SUMS. If not you don't have the complete file/something is wrong with it.